# pyttsx3/pyttsx4 give segmentation fault: 11

Tags: python-3.x, segmentation-fault, pyttsx3

I'm trying to use the pyttsx3 module but it crashes the python env and gives me a segmentation fault as soon as I call the pyttsx3.init() method. Thought it might be an issue of pyttsx3 being outdated so I tried the same with pyttsx4 but no luck.

```
>>> import pyttsx4
>>> pyttsx4.init()
Segmentation fault: 11
```

It worked perfectly fine when I used it last month. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the modules several times. I tried running it in a conda evn with python 3.8, 3.10 and on my local env with python 3.11.